# curl does not have same result as browser

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

I am trying to download the following URL using from command line using curl. If the same URL is requested through the browser, it is able to fetch the image. But for curl, the server terminates the SSL handshake. Just to use exact same parameters; I tried the curl commands from 'developer tools' from google-chrome and firefox. But both fails with following error.

This question was asked before here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969016/curl-returns-35-openssl-ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall) but there is no answer that works. I tried -http1.1 as suggested but did not work.

https://floridakeyswebcams.tv/sloppycam/camarchive/0807.jpg

```
(base) (15:39 test@testcomp ~) > curl -v 'https://floridakeyswebcams.tv/sloppycam/camarchive/0807.jpg' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,mr;q=0.7' -H 'If-None-Match: "90cbf2d5a81d51:da782"' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Fri, 03 May 2019 12:07:53 GMT' --compressed
*   Trying 74.209.245.140...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to floridakeyswebcams.tv (74.209.245.140) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/sagham/anaconda2/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to         floridakeyswebcams.tv:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to floridakeyswebcams.tv:443
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it appears that floridakeyswebcams.tv requires TLS1.3 support, use the `--tlsv1.3` argument,

```
curl --tlsv1.3 -v 'https://floridakeyswebcams.tv/sloppycam/camarchive/0807.jpg'
```

here is what i get when using `--tlsv1.2`:

```
$ ./CURL.EXE https://floridakeyswebcams.tv/sloppycam/camarchive/0807.jpg --tlsv1.2 -vv
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 74.209.245.140...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to floridakeyswebcams.tv (74.209.245.140) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ALGORITHM_MISMATCH (0x80090331) - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorit
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with floridakeyswebcams.tv port 443
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ALGORITHM_MISMATCH (0x80090331) - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorit
```

and here is (roughly, it was printed in the wrong order for some reason) what i get if i use `--tlsv1.3`:

```
./CURL.EXE https://floridakeyswebcams.tv/sloppycam/camarchive/0807.jpg --tlsv1.3 -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to floridakeyswebcams.tv (74.209.245.140) port 443 (#0)

> GET /sloppycam/camarchive/0807.jpg HTTP/1.1


> Host: floridakeyswebcams.tv


> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1


> Accept: */*


> 

▒▒▒▒
\▒.▒:\▒.▒:▒▒











▒▒
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

-truncated jpg binary-

question still remains about why this wasn't auto-negotiated tho, i'm not sure but i guess your TLS backend doesn't support tlv1.3, and that probably has something to do with why you just got a cryptic error..

Comment: Thanks! The cryptic error is because the server just terminated the connection without any response in the middle of SSL handshake, I think.